# Accuracy function in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I Want to compute the accuracy of a numerical vector that contains 12 forecasts but I get this result with a warning.

```
accuracy(f,Test)
                    ME      RMSE       MAE       MPE      MAPE ACF1 Theil's U
Training set       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NA        NA
Test set     0.9064933 0.9064933 0.9064933 0.4060658 0.4060658   NA        NA
Warning message:
In trainingaccuracy(f, test, d, D) : test elements must be within sample`

Test : ` Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul
2012 223.23801 203.51890 195.21139 169.68900 157.63439 135.79616  96.84895
           Aug       Sep       Oct       Nov       Dec
2012 100.42089  62.51129  49.18672  22.10280   5.00000
```

I get `f` by this code :

```
f  <- list()

for (i in 1:12) { 
  demfit <- ets(Dem2) 
  f[[i]] <- forecast(demfit, 1)  #start filling the f list with values
  Dem2[length(Dem2)+1] <- f[[1]]$mean[1]
} 

f <- unlist(f)
```

This code aim to get one-step ahead forecasts 12 times ( at each time, I update my serie by the forecast value)

Thank you for your help

My data :

```
     Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr    May    Jun    Jul 
2008 514.43 508.07 505.13 486.00 482.20 470.37 447.30 
2009 394.93 381.19 381.94 363.38 361.50 352.96 334.86 
2010 336.10 320.44 324.10 311.16 303.78 305.80 285.19 
2011 260.85 258.78 271.43 271.43 267.46 271.77 254.83 
2012 223.23 203.51 195.21 169.68 157.63 135.79 96.84 

     Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov    Dec 
2008 438.83 415.91 408.44 409.67 395.52 
2009 340.41 326.41 331.14330 337.07 336.51 
2010 297.95 274.93 272.91 268.58 271.35 
2011 266.91 242.42 241.04 230.29 233.57 
2012 100.42 62.51 49.18 22.10 5
```

Comment: questions like this should be post at stackoverflow since this is just about programming in $R$

Comment: What packages do you use? What is `Test`, `d` and `D`? What method do you use? What is your data? The error message suggests that you possibly do something wrong in your code, but without seeing the code and knowing the context we cannot help. Provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I'm using forecast package

Comment: @Tim: see lines 104 and 121 of https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/R/errors.R

Answer (score 0):

Check the [accuracy](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/accuracy) function documentation, it says that `f` should be

> An object of class "forecast", or a numerical vector containing
>   forecasts. It will also work with Arima, ets and lm objects if x is
>   omitted – in which case in-sample accuracy measures are returned.

While what you provide is a list of such objects - that is not the same.